How to change border radius of Tabs component in NextUI
I have a problem in the tabs component of nextui. I want to change the radius as in the picture but the element is not in the code structure. How to solve it?
]
]

I tried with className={{ wrapper: ‘rounded-lg’}} in child element but it still doesn't work.

Problem :

How to change border radius of inner & outer part of Tabs component in NextUI

Cause :

There is no property/key wrapper for classNames in Tabs component.

Solution :
There are 2 ways to change radius :

for custom border-radius, classNames
radius prop

1. Using classNames prop for custom border-radius :

classNames has keys


base｜ tabList｜ tab｜ tabContent｜ cursor ｜ panel

Tabs component has prop classNames pass border-radius to tabList & cursor keys in it to get desired result.
Code:
<Tabs
    classNames={{
        tabList: "rounded-xl bg-secondary", // Changes Border radius of outer part
        cursor: "rounded-sm",  //  Changes Border radius of inner part
    }}
>

Explaination :

tabList : is the part that contains the tab names buttons(cursor)
cursor : is the button that we click to change tab


2. Using radius prop :
radius prop valid values :

none | sm | md | lg | full

Code :
<Tabs radius={'lg'}>

Please Read :

Tab Props : https://nextui.org/docs/components/tabs#tabs-props
Custom Styles : https://nextui.org/docs/components/tabs#custom-styles
Radius : https://nextui.org/docs/components/tabs#radius


If this answer was solved your problem then mark it as solution.  If
this answer was very helpful then you may upvote.  If you have any
doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer as
necessary)

